# How to add a horizontal line to Button in Android?

Tags: android, button

I'm making a grid of cells and each cell is a button that is clickable. I want to add a horizontal line to the button when it is clicked like that:
[image: here is an example]

Could any one help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If simply striking through the text would suffice, create your own `SpannedString` with a `StrikethroughSpan` and use that for the `Button` text.

Comment: but it will cover the text only, not the whole cell

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this would be to create your own 9-patches for the Button. You can create them with any image editor (I usually use Gimp), but make sure you resave them with the draw-9-patch tool in your android-sdk directory because it adds the necessary formating to the 9.png. Check out [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) for more information regarding 9-patches. Once you've finished creating the two 9-patches for the Button you will need to create an xml file in your drawable folder which will select which image to choose based on the Button's current state, check out [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/) for more info on creating a selector for a button. It's a decent amount of work, but it's worth it to do it the correct way.

Comment: And after the user clicks the `Button` how is the line going to be kept on the `Button`?

Comment: Luksprog is right, you'd probably be better of using a ToggleButton (since it intrinsically keeps an on/off state) instead of a default Button. But the implementation would be the same in order to set the background drawable of the ToggleButton.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final StrikethroughSpan STRIKE_THROUGH_SPAN = new StrikethroughSpan();
Spannable spannable = (Spannable) button.getText();
spannable.setSpan(STRIKE_THROUGH_SPAN, 0, button.getText().length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Have a look at these link for better understanding::

1. [StrikethroughSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StrikethroughSpan.html)
2. [Spannable.setSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html#setSpan%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot but i the strike didn't cover the whole cell, it covers only the text!!